# Hide/show elements in a list using multiple checkbox fieldsets with jQuery

Tags: jquery, list, filter

I have the following html list:

```
<ul id="results">
    <li class="music beginner">Music, Beginner</li>
    <li class="music expert">Music, Expert</li>
    <li class="cooking beginner">Cooking, Beginner</li>
    <li class="cooking expert">Cooking, Expert</li>
</ul>
```

The class attribute of each list item contains values I'd like to use to filter (i.e. show/hide) them based on a user's selections in a list of checkbox inputs:

```
<form id="filter-container">
    <fieldset id="course-type">
        <label>Course Type</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="music" />Music
        <input type="checkbox" name="cooking" />Cooking
    </fieldset>
<br />
    <fieldset id="course-level">
        <label>Course Level</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="beginner" />Beginner
        <input type="checkbox" name="expert" />Expert
    </fieldset> 
</form>
```

When the user clicks on any of the checkboxes, the following jquery runs in an attempt to show only the list items whose class values correspond to the name values of the checked inputs:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

//make sure browser clears all checked boxes on reload
$(':checkbox:checked').prop('checked',false);

//hide all results
$('#results > li').hide();

//When any checkbox inside #filter-container is clicked ...
$('#filter-container').find('input:checkbox').live('click', function () {

    // ... 1. hide all results
    $('#results > li').hide();

    // ... 2. find the checked boxes in the "course-type" fieldset
    $('#course-type').find('input:checked').each(function () {

        // ... 3. show the results whose class has the value of the checked boxes'name
        $('#results > li.' + $(this).attr('name')).show();
    });

    // ... 4. find the checked boxes in the "course-level" fieldset
    $('#course-level').find('input:checked').each(function () {

        // ... 5. hide the results whose class doesn't have the value of the checked boxes' name
        $('#results > li:not(.' + $(this).attr('name')).hide();

    });
}); 
});
```

The result almost works. The trouble I'm having is with the second ("course-level") fieldset. If user clicks on "music" for example, it produces the desired result, which is that both "beginner" and "expert" level music list items show. If user then clicks on "beginner," the desired result also is produced: the "expert" music list item is hidden. The problem is that when user next clicks on "expert," i.e. he wants to see both beginner AND expert music results, both music results are hidden.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5a255e0j/

I believe the issue is that this line is only hiding items but not showing them, but I haven't been able to resolve:

```
$('#results > li:not(.' + $(this).attr('name')).hide();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I form a selector corresponding to each option group and filter by each to form list to show.This code also has the 'all' checkbox in each checkbox group -  if that is selected I use the select all selector '*'.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //make sure browser clears all checked boxes on reload
    $(':checkbox:checked').prop('checked',false);

    //check all of the "All" boxes on reload
    $('input.all').prop('checked',true);

    //When any checkbox inside #filter-container is clicked ...
    $('#filter-container').find('input:checkbox').live('click',    function () {
    var items = $('#results > li');
    var all_courses = $('#course-type input.all');
    var all_levels = $('#course-level input.all');
    // ... 1. hide all results
    items.hide();

    var course_sel = '*';
    if( ! all_courses.prop('selected'))
    {
        course_sel = 
        $('#course-type').find('input:checked').map(function () {    
        return '.' + $(this).attr('name');
        }).get().join();

    }

    var level_sel = '*';
    if( ! all_levels.prop('selected'))
    {
       level_sel = 
       $('#course-level').find('input:checked').map(function () {
       return '.' + $(this).attr('name');
       }).get().join();

   }

   items.filter(course_sel).filter(level_sel).show();
   });



});
```

Comment: Perfect - exactly what I was hoping for!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you're trying to do is the following:

Show all the courses of the checked type(s) **unless** one of the level checkboxes is checked, in which cases only show the courses of the checked level and type.

That's confusing for the user and for the code because it means that you want to see if beginner level classes if **either** the beginner checkbox is checked OR the beginner checkbox is unchecked and the expert checkbox is also unchecked. So whether you see beginner courses depends not only on the beginner checkbox but also the expert checkbox.

I think a simpler model is to leave all the level checkboxes checked and then simply show the courses for the checked level and type.

Regardless of which model you go with, the trick is to iterate through the items and make sure that each classname of the item should be displayed as follows:

```
    // ... 2. Hide all the results containing an unchecked class name
$('#results > li').each(function () {
    var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");
    for ( var i = 0, l = classes.length; i<l; ++i ) {
        if (!($("input:checkbox[name='" + classes[i] +"']").is(':checked'))) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Here's the jsfiddle for my implementation of my simpler model:
http://jsfiddle.net/dvew4yq3/

And here's my jsfiddle for my implementation of your original model:
http://jsfiddle.net/c4dp7gqk/

Comment: Thanks for this! I might end up going in this direction. But the issue of whether my example is confusing for the user is kind of irrelevant since the example is just the first piece. I didn't want to add the second piece to my example because I didn't want to add another variable to the problem. The final result will have "All Courses" and "All Levels" checkboxes that (I think) solves the usability issue. Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5a255e0j/2/. Issue is with the "levels" filter -- if both are clicked, it's still trying to show results that have both levels, and there are none.